# Why Lucene does not provide a Real Time Search and has slow commits?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to use Lucene in one of the application with OLTP processing, which requires real time search and transactional capabilities.

I have been extensively bugging around Apache Solr, Elastic Search and Lucene and trying to understand, Why Lucene commit is expensive and why there is no Real Time Search, but only NRT.

Answer (score 0):

**Q>** Why Lucene commit is expensive?
**A>** Because it deals with I/O. It has to, among other things, do `fsync()`, write a new segments_N file, write deleted docs to disk, merge, and so on.

**Q>** why there is no Real Time Search, but only NRT?
**A>** Because this is how Lucene's API is designed: `IndexSearcher` is only a thin layer upon `IndexReader` which contains all the data.

You might want to read [this article](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html) to get more details on the internals.

Comment: Ok. Let's take an assumption that we want to have commit per document index, so I don't think there would be any merges, let's keep the number of segments to 1 as well. And talking about I/O, I don't believe that alone can add to so much latency. Compared to a typical disk writes and a database commit like Cassandra or Mysql, it is much expensive.

Comment: I think your comments are only valid if you can provide us with analysis/benchmark containing _some_ numbers. Slow/expensive is a vague term.

Comment: Yes, Agreed I did run some benchmarks using Solr, with commit per document index, and it resulted around 8 TPS, while with batch commit, it can go huge till 3000 OPS or more as well.

Comment: But what more, I am looking at is the way Lucene is doing commits, because that metrics looks strange to me.